# Json Data print after insert a record using Jquery Ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

**I am using Jquery Ajax in Codeigniter, after register a user via bootstrap modal I got JSON data as below instead of fetching the data from table. Where I am wrong? please help!**

{"success":true,"type":"add"}

**Here is my Jquery function**

````
```
<script>
$(function(){
    display();
    //add new

function display(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'ajax',
        url:'<?php echo base_url()?>frame_cont/display',

        async: false,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            var html='';
            var i;
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                html +='<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].username+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].password+'</td>'+
                            '<tr>';
            }
            $('#showdata').html(html);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Could not get Data from Database');
        }
});
};
});
</script>```
````

**and here is controller class**

```
<?php 
class Frame_cont extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->load->model('frame');
        $result=$this->frame->insert();
        $msg['success']=false;
        $msg['type']='add';
        if($result){
            $msg['success']=true;
        }
        echo json_encode($msg);
        }




    public function display(){
        $this->load->model('frame');
        $result=$this->frame->display();
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

**This is all about the code and sorry for the english**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occur because of I am using type="submit" instead of type="button" in my form button.

Answer (score 1):

in your register function you doing `echo json_encode($msg);` at the end. you should echo inserted value inside if condition